# Linq-to-Sql count() returning 0 even if there is row returning

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq-to-sql

It is not very clear to me why I am not able to get the number of rows returned using linq-to-sql

I had this query to use as validation:

```
var obj1 = (from c in context.sistema_DocType_Index
where c.indexId == id
select c).First();

if(obj1 != null) {}
```

I was getting a null exception using First() method if there was no row returned. Ok, so I decided to use Count().

```
var obj1 = (from c in context.sistema_DocType_Index
where c.indexId == id
select c).Count();

if(obj1  > 0) {}
```

I have 3 rows returning from the database but the Count() gives me 0.
Why is that?

Comment: Are you sure there is a row with the specified `id`? If this id field is unique you will only get 1 row and not 3 rows anyway.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` will return null instead of throwing an exception if there are no rows, and `Any()` will probably map even better to what you want.

Comment: How did you know that you *have 3 rows returning from the database*?

Comment: Check your connection string to make sure you are looking at the correct database.

Comment: Yes... the is 3. It is not a uniq id. I performed this query in the database. That is how I checked. Any has solved my problem. Thanh you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Any();`method. which is the best use for this case. [Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx)

```
if( YourDataCollection.Any(SomeCOndtion==SOmeValue))
 { 
 //  do some logic
 }
```